# Faster way to check substring of a biginteger

Tags: java

I'm given a big integer (number of digits can reach up to 300000). I should find how many substrings of the integer is divisible by 4.
My code is pretty slow. Any advice to make it faster is appreciated.

```
public static void solve() throws IOException {
  String s = (new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in))).readLine();
  int l = s.length(), d = 0; // d is number of substrings divisible by 4
  BigInteger f = new BigInteger("4");
  for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j <= l; j++) {
      String te = (s.substring(i,j)).replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""); //regex used for leading zeros
      if( te.charAt(te.length()-1) == '3' || te.charAt(te.length()-1) == '5' || te.charAt(te.length()-1) == '7' || te.charAt(te.length()-1) == '9' )
        continue;
      else {
        BigInteger temp = new BigInteger(te);
        if ( (temp.mod(f)).toString().equals("0") )
          d++;
      }
    }
   }
  System.out.println( d );
}
```

Comment: Hint: you only need to consider the last two digits of a number to determine if it is divisible by 4.

Comment: If you want faster, then you should probably try to get rid of regexes and strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an integer is divisible by 4, either the number is less than ten and ends with 0, 4 or 8; or the last two digits are divisible by 4.

If the first character of the string is itself divisible by four, that is one of the substrings you are trying to count.

If the pair of divisible-by-four digits occur at positions `i-1` and `i` in the string, then there are `i + 1` substrings with that suffix if the number starts with an even numbers, and `i` substrings if the number starts with an odd number.

As such, you can count the number of substrings divisible by 4 as follows:

```
int v = 0;
long cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
  int w = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
  if ((v * 10 + w) % 4 == 0) {
    cnt += i;
  }
  if (w % 4 == 0) {
    ++cnt;
  }
  v = w;
}
```

Comment: Yours looks nicer having only one loop. However, I believe it undercounts as well, since it does not consider one digit substrings (0, 4 or 8) except for the first position.

Comment: @sfThomas true. Corrected (I think). Actually, that helps with the handling of the first one-digit number too. Good spot.

Comment: @Andy Turner it works much faster&better, but still undercounts, don't know why. Is there any case not counted in your code, to me it seems allright.

Comment: @Geek what input undercounts for you?

Comment: @Andy Turner for most of cases. here is one of them
    2144315253572020279108092911160072328496568665545836825277616363478721946398140227406814602154768031

Answer should be 1528 but output of the code above is 1516

Comment: @Geek I think it should be fixed now. It was ignoring the case where the substring ends with a number divisible by 4, but the preceding number is odd (e.g. 10) - that makes "all preceding substrings" not divisible by 4, but the substring of that single character *is* divisible by 4.

Comment: @Andy Turner also the cases which have leading zeros should also be counted as a new one. For example  10412 you can take 0 4 12 as divisible substrings but 04 could be dropped in your code and this number should have 4 substring divisible by 4: 0  04  4  12

UPD: it now works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger sumOfAll = new BigInteger("123232312321321412343213421321321312");
System.out.println("First Ten Digits: " + sumOfAll.toString().substring(0, 10));
```